# Group by & Order by in the same statement (per month)

Tags: mysql, group-by, sql-order-by

Is is possible to group by and order by in the same statement? The below statement outputs the months in a random order. It produces the correct figures etc, however i would like to show the months as Jan,Feb,March, April etc. in order

```
SELECT coalesce(date_format(TRANSACTION_DATE, '%M'), 'Grand Total') AS MONTH,
ROUND(SUM(SALES_AMOUNT),2) TOTAL, SUM(QUANTITY) AS TOTAL_QUANTITY
FROM SALES
WHERE YEAR(TRANSACTION_DATE) = 2018
GROUP BY month WITH ROLLUP;

April       30826.68    476
August      39703.85    619
December    36986.16    515
February    34531.15    463
January     45163.22    596
July        37640.08    506
June        37284.25    496
March       44194.98    621
May         39016.04    576
November    39161.90    521
October     34447.61    485
September   34958.94    498
            453914.86   6372
```

Answer (score 1):

> Is is possible to group by and order by in the same statement?
>   Yes, that is possible just you need to work around it.

If you can get rid of the rollup from this query you can do the ordering like this:

```
SELECT coalesce(date_format(TRANSACTION_DATE, '%M'), 'Grand Total') AS MONTH, ROUND(SUM(SALES_AMOUNT),2) TOTAL, SUM(QUANTITY) AS TOTAL_QUANTITY FROM SALES WHERE YEAR(TRANSACTION_DATE) = 2018 GROUP BY month order by month(TRANSACTION_DATE) asc;
```

Answer (score 0):

This should order the months in the expected order:

```
SELECT coalesce(date_format(TRANSACTION_DATE, '%M'), 'Grand Total') AS MONTH,
ROUND(SUM(SALES_AMOUNT),2) TOTAL, SUM(QUANTITY) AS TOTAL_QUANTITY
FROM SALES
WHERE YEAR(TRANSACTION_DATE) = 2018
GROUP BY month WITH ROLLUP
ORDER BY date_format(TRANSACTION_DATE, '%m');
```

Notice the lower case `m` in the order by. That's for the numerical representation of the month.